Azure low priority VMs not starting
I do not have a spot instance enabled on any vms, and they are in dedicated host groups. In resource health I see that my vms are preempted due to low priority.
How do I resolve it?
Restarted the vms but still does not work.
Tried most things except resizing and recreating.

Why is your low-priority VM is being preempted?
Low priority VMs are discounted VMs that are allocated from the unused capacity of Azure VMs in a particular region, to anyone upon request.
Low priority VMs take advantage of surplus capacity in Azure. The tradeoff is they may not always be available to be allocated, or may be preempted at any time, depending on available capacity.
For this reason, low-priority VMs are most suitable for batch and asynchronous processing workloads where the job completion time is flexible, can be checkpointed, and the work is distributed across many VMs.
Preemptible VMs can be of two types. Low priority VMs (legacy type), and Spot VMs. Both have the same functionality and use case.

May i know what exactly do you mean by the 1st low priority vm type, the legacy type, is it because it is in a host group. Basically how did my vm become a low priority one., when I didn't set any such configuration to make it a low priority, btw thanks a ton for answering to my post.

Supposedly batch accounts that use the Batch managed pool allocation mode always get low-priority VMs. Low priority VMs will be retired on September 30, 2025 and can be migrated to Spot VMs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-spot-vms

Sorry didn't thank you., Thanks a lot for the info.
